How to take a nested array of amounts, divide them by months and days and then return a new value?
I have a backend that fetches a list of users. Each user pays a monthly subscription, which can sometimes vary depending on other factors.
On the frontend I can see the total amount each user has paid by entering dates in input fields that has "from date" and "to date".
So if I have 3 users that each paid 100 every month from 1st of January to 1st of April,
the output in devtools would look something like this:
 users: [
      {
        0: [{
          userName: 'user 1',
          amountPaid: 300
        }],

        1: [{
          userName: 'user 2',
          amountPaid: 300
        }],

        2: [{
          userName: 'user 3',
          amountPaid: 300
        }]
      }
    ]

The problem is that I need to create a functionality that takes days into consideration when calculating the total amount the users paid.
so if I have a fromDate which is 2024-01-01 and a toDate which is 2024-03-15
then I need the calculation to be:
100 (Jan) + 100 (Feb) + 48.39 ( 15 ÷ 31 x 100 )
So for March, instead of outputting 100, it should output the number of days between the first day of March and the selected end date (15th), divided with the amount for that month.
I have done the following setup:
splitTotalPaidIntoMonths(){
        this.diffBetweenDatesMonthFormat = moment(this.toDate).diff(this.fromDate, 'month')
        this.toDateMonthStartDate = moment(this.toDate).startOf('month')
        this.compareToDateWithToDateMonthStart = moment(this.toDate).diff(this.toDateMonthStartDate, 'days')
        if(this.users){
          this.totalPaymentDividedByMonths = this.users[0].amountPaid / this.diffBetweenDatesMonthFormat;
        }
      },

showUsers() {
    this.users = null;
    this.init = true;
    axiosDatabaseService.getUsers(
      moment(this.fromDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
      moment(this.toDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
      .then(result => {
        this.users = result.data;
      })
  },

My idea is to:
1: Figure out the amount of months there are between fromDate and toDate.
2: Figure out the amount of days there are between the 1st day in the month of the toDate and the selected date entered in toDate.
3: When users have been fetched from the database, then look at the total amount for each user, and then divide that amount with the number of months selected. So if the total amount for three users are 300, and 3 months have been selected, then I want to populate new arrays for each user which consists of the total amount split into 3, so 100, 100, 100 for each.
Like this:
    totalPaymentDividedByMonths: [
  {
    0: [{
      amountPaid: [ { 100, 100, 100 } ]
    }],

    1: [{
      amountPaid: [ { 100, 100, 100 } ]
    }],

    2: [{
      amountPaid: [ { 100, 100, 100 } ]
    }]
  }
]


IF the selected date for the toDate is in the middle of the month (for exmaple 15th of March), then select one of the amounts in each user array, and then run the calculation: 15 ÷ 31 x 100, so now each array will have 100, 100, 48.39.
 0: [{
   amountPaid: [ { 100, 100, 48.39 } ]
 }],

 1: [{
   amountPaid: [ { 100, 100, 48.39 } ]
 }],

 2: [{
   amountPaid: [ { 100, 100, 48.39 } ]
 }]


Combine the amounts again, with the new result. So: 100 + 100 + 48.39

Replace the amount in users.amountPaid with the new amount, so instead of 300, it should show 248.39.
         0: [{
           userName: 'user 1',
           amountPaid: 248.39
         }],

         1: [{
           userName: 'user 2',
           amountPaid: 248.39
         }],

         2: [{
           userName: 'user 3',
           amountPaid: 248.39
         }]



As you can see, my idea is rather convoluted, but I don't know how else to do it. I tried to fiddle with the backend, but I am mainly a frontend developer, so I want to find a frontend solution.
My problem right now is that I am not sure how to go forward, and I have reached a point where my own code is confusing me. My totalPaymentDividedByMonths array does not get populated with the users and the divided amounts.
I tried doing the following:
this.totalPaymentDividedByMonths = (num = this.users[0].totalAmount, n = this.diffBetweenDatesMonthFormat) => new Array(n).fill(num / n);

Is there an easier way to do this approach on the frontend?

I have created a JSFiddle with a working example of what you are trying to achieve.
 Vue.component('vue2-examples', Vue2Examples.default);
 
 new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
         subscriptionAmount: 100,
         fromDate: new Date('2024-01-01'),
       toDate: new Date('2024-03-15'),
       users: [
         {
           0: [{
             userName: 'user 1',
             amountPaid: 100
           }],
           1: [{
             userName: 'user 2',
             amountPaid: 200
           }],
           2: [{
             userName: 'user 3',
             amountPaid: 300
           }]
         }
       ]
   },
   mounted() {
     const daysAccountedFor = this.toDate.getUTCDate()
     
     // takes toDates month and adds it by 1, also first day -> 2024-04-01
     const nextMonth = new Date(this.toDate.getFullYear(), this.toDate.getMonth() + 1, 1);
   
       // Subtract one day -> 2024-03-31
     const lastDayOfMonth = new Date(nextMonth.getTime() - 86400000);
     const numberOfDays = lastDayOfMonth.getUTCDate();
   
     console.log("Number of days in the month:", numberOfDays); // Output: 31
     
     let temp = []
         this.users.forEach(user => {
       for (const key in user) {
         user[key].forEach(u => {
           console.log(u)
 
           let exactAmount = u.amountPaid - (this.subscriptionAmount - (daysAccountedFor/numberOfDays * this.subscriptionAmount))
 
           temp.push(+exactAmount.toFixed(2))
         });
       };
       });
     
     this.users = temp
   }
 });

